# Ошибка при создании отображаемой секции функцией NtCreateSection в питоне

Tags: python, windows

получаю ошибку при создании секции в памяти с помощью функции NtCreateSection, функция возвращает ошибку 0xc000001f(STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE). На С++ такой ошибки не было. Кто сталкивался с этим или может подсказать буду благодарен. Спасибо.

{Неправильное сопоставление} Размер создаваемого представления для секции памяти превышает размер этой секции.- Читайте подробнее на: https://allerrorcodes.ru/ntstatus

Вот код для примера

```
from defines import *

ntdll = windll.ntdll
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
ntdll.NtCreateSection.argtypes = [PHANDLE, ULONG, POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, PLARGE_INTEGER, ULONG, ULONG, HANDLE]
ntdll.NtCreateSection.restypes = NTSTATUS
h_sec = LPVOID(0)
status = ntdll.NtCreateSection(byref(h_sec),
                                  SECTION_ALL_ACCESS,
                                  None,
                                  None,
                                  PAGE_READONLY,
                                  SEC_IMAGE,
                                  None)
print(hex(0xFFFFFFFF + status))// 0xc000001f
```

Пробовал передавать другие флаги в параметрах функции не помогло.